# Difference between sencha app build -run and sencha app run?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Is there a significant difference between the commands `sencha app build -run native` and `sencha app run native`.

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/cordova_phonegap.html), it looks like `run` builds the app before running it.
[Here](https://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/getting_started/using_creating_builds.html) it says that `build -run` launches it on the appropriate simulator, but I suppose if the device is connected, it just runs it on the device, so there isn't really a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that you are right. `sencha help app build` and `sencha help app run` give me almost the same amount of options and behave pretty much similar. So, I'd say that `sencha app build -run native` is a shorthand for `sencha app run native` Moreover, it totally makes sense because if you want to run your app you have to build it first.